# Ho to dispaly past days report using MS Access query

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, switch-statement, iif

```
SELECT Name,
SUM(Switch([Date] = DateAdd('d', - 7, DATE ()), NetAmount) )AS DAY1 
FROM Customer GROUP BY Name
```

The above query works fine but my question is I want to return the value 0 for the empty field in the MS Access database. if the date is not present in the database means. .

either use `switch` or `iif` please help me . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function NZ(value, value_if_null) should do the trick.